# Error in Decimal Calculation in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, decimal, date-arithmetic

I am doing a windows form application in C# to  calculate tax and add with total. after getting the total with a button click it should calculate the tax amount. if there are no decimal numbers it is working, but when it have to calculate decimal numbers giving an error as "the input string is not in correct format"

```
TotTax.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textboxnettotal.Text) * (0.12)).ToString();
            textBox_GrnTot.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textboxnettotal.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(TotTax.Text)).ToString();
```

and this my code

1. while i am calculating total in c column of a data gridview decimal numbers it is not giving me the decimal value but i am getting Balanced full no answer in total textbox.

   ```
             int sum = 0;
           for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
           {
               sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
           }
                 textboxnettotal.Text = sum.ToString();
           RowCount++;
   ```

Comment: And where's the decimal you are talking about? You are converting all to `int`.

Comment: I tried with decimal but error. yah converting all to int

Comment: Which culture you are in???

Comment: Hmm, strange. It worked for me when I used decimal...

Comment: where do u use decimal @SuperPrograman

Comment: I forgot, I will check soon... :) Where were _you_ trying?

Answer (score 3):

Use `Convert.ToDecimal` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`, to be sure your `sum` is declared as `decimal`.

Answer (score 1):

`int` that you are converting to with `Convert.ToInt32` doesn't support decimals. Use the `Decimal` data type instead. It allows decimals and it doesn't have some of the odd rounding behaviour of `float` or `double`.

Comment: i just tried with float and double now giving an error "sum += Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);" under data gridview1 having some invalid argument

Comment: @user2979006 what's the actual value of `Cells[5].Value`? It should be  parsable to decimal. Otherwise you have to use `TryParse`, however in that case **your data is really wrong designed**.

Comment: that will change as variable. where it is wrongly designed sorry i am a newbee @King King

Comment: @user2979006 the column at index `5` should be of type `decimal` if you use `DataSource`, provide some validation to check for user input and you will never encounter such an issue.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Tryparse()` method with `InvariantCulture`

```
decimal myvalue;
if (decimal.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out myvalue))
{
  sum += myvalue;
 }
```

**Complete Code:**

```
decimal myvalue;
decimal sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    if (decimal.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out myvalue))
    {
      sum += myvalue;
     }
}
  textboxnettotal.Text = sum.ToString();
  RowCount++;
```

Comment: just tried but showing entire part inside the bracket is wrong

Comment: you mean compile error? could you please check the edited answer?

Comment: it might be due to some curly braces {} missing or something, could you please edit the question with latest code?

Comment: please edit your question with latest code with which you are trying.

Comment: @user2979006: check my edited answer with complete code section. Works Perfectly now.

Comment: the best overloaded match for "decimal.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out myvalue"  has some invalid argument

Comment: see you are missing 2 )) brackets at the end of the statement use => if (decimal.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out myvalue))

Comment: check wether your both variables (sum and myvalue) are decimal => decimal myvalue;
decimal sum = 0;

Comment: same. but not working!! confused :( thanks ur big try and help @sudhakar

Answer (score 0):

```
double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        sum += Convert.Todouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
    }
          textboxnettotal.Text = sum.ToString();
    RowCount++;
```